# How to fix infinite jump bug in pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to make a game, but you can keep spamming "w" (jump) for infinite height which is really bad when you are trying to make a platformer game. This is all my code:

```
GRAVITY = .2

diedorgameover = False
while not diedorgameover:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            diedorgameover = True

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_a:
                x_change = -5
            elif event.key == pygame.K_d:
                x_change = 5
            elif event.key == pygame.K_s:
                y_change = 5
            elif event.key == pygame.K_w:
                y_change = -5

        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_a or event.key == pygame.K_d:
                x_change = 0
            if event.key == pygame.K_s or event.key == pygame.K_w:
                y_change = 0

    #adding gravity to y_value
    y_change += GRAVITY 
    x += x_change
    y += y_change

    if y >= gameDisplay.get_height() - 68:
        y = gameDisplay.get_height() - 68
        y_change = 0

    #draw everything   
    gameDisplay.blit(background_image,(0,0))
    red(x,y)

    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)


pygame.quit()
quit()
```

I would really appreciate it if you have any insight on this problem.

Comment: To help you we would need to see more of your code. The lines you posted look good...

Comment: OK here's more of my code ' #adding gravity to y_value
    y_change += GRAVITY 
    x += x_change
    y += y_change

    
     
    if y >= gameDisplay.get_height() - 68:
        y = gameDisplay.get_height() - 68
        y_change = 0

         

    #draw everything   
    gameDisplay.blit(background_image,(0,0))
    red(x,y)   
    
   '

Comment: That really does not help muc more: you did not show us the point where you receive the user input. Also please edit your question to show the extended code.

Comment: Please always post a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) here and read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define a `on_ground` variable that you set to `True` if the player touches the ground. When the user wants to jump (presses 'w') you first check `if on_ground:` and then change the `y_change` and set `on_ground` to `False`.

```
import pygame


pygame.init()

gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

GRAVITY = .5

player_img = pygame.Surface((30, 50))
player_img.fill((40, 120, 200))
x = 100
y = 500
x_change = 0
y_change = 0
on_ground = False

diedorgameover = False
while not diedorgameover:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            diedorgameover = True
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_a:
                x_change = -5
            elif event.key == pygame.K_d:
                x_change = 5
            elif event.key == pygame.K_s:
                y_change = 5
            elif event.key == pygame.K_w:
                # Only jump if the player is on the ground.
                if on_ground:
                    y_change = -12
                    on_ground = False
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_a or event.key == pygame.K_d:
                x_change = 0

    y_change += GRAVITY
    x += x_change
    y += y_change

    # If the player is on the ground.
    if y >= gameDisplay.get_height() - 68:
        y = gameDisplay.get_height() - 68
        y_change = 0
        on_ground = True

    gameDisplay.fill((30, 30, 30))
    gameDisplay.blit(player_img, (x, y))

    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)


pygame.quit()
```

Also delete these lines, otherwise the player can stop while in the air if the key is released:

```
if event.key == pygame.K_s or event.key == pygame.K_w:
    y_change = 0
```

Comment: i think I am starting to really grip these concepts now!

Answer (score 0):

```
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        running = False
    if event.type == KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == K_SPACE and y_change == 0:  # if spacebar is pressed and y_change is 0
            y_change = 18                        # set y_change to 18
if y_change > 0 and player_y == 200:       # if y_change is greater than 0 and player_y is 200
    player_y -= y_change
    y_change -= gravity
if player_y > 200:
    player_y = 200
if player_y == 200 and y_change < 0:
    y_change = 0
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).