# How do I fix my 'Jump'?

Tags: python, pygame

I am new to this website and pygame so bear with me. I am experimenting with pygame and made a simple platformer. However, whenever I 'Jump', the block jumps frame by frame, so I have to hold down the spacebar. Any help would be greatly appreciated!
here is my code:

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
win = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))
x = 0
y = 490
width = 10
height = 10
vel = 5
pygame.key.set_repeat(1)
isjump = False
jumpcount = 10
while True:
    pygame.time.delay(30)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            break
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keys[pygame.K_a] and x>vel-5:
            x -= vel
        if keys[pygame.K_d] and x < 500 - width:
            x += vel
        if not(isjump):
            if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
                isjump = True
        else:
            if jumpcount >= -10:
                neg = 1
                if jumpcount < 0:
                    neg = -1
                y -= (jumpcount ** 2) /2 * neg
                jumpcount -= 1
            else:
                isjump = False
                jumpcount = 10
        win.fill((0, 0, 0))
        pygame.draw.rect(win, (255, 255, 255), (x, y, width, height))
        pygame.display.update()
pygame.quit()
```

Comment: I suspect you only see a change when you call the `update` method. So, you will only see one change to `y` per one space bar press. If you did the update in a loop you could move it more. What do you want jump to do? Make the block appear somewhere else? Or move for a while?

Answer (score 3):

You are mixing your keyboard event handling with your jump-logic. I've done two things, change the spacebar detection to trigger `isjump` and handle the jump logic irregardless of whether there is a key pressed or not:

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
win = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))
x = 0
y = 490
width = 10
height = 10
vel = 5
pygame.key.set_repeat(1)
isjump = False
jumpcount = 10
while True:
    pygame.time.delay(30)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            break
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keys[pygame.K_a] and x>vel-5:
            x -= vel
        if keys[pygame.K_d] and x < 500 - width:
            x += vel
        # if we're not already jumping, check if space is pressed to start a jump
        if not isjump and keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
            isjump = True
            jumpcount = 10
    # if we're supposed to jump, handle the jump logic
    if isjump:
        if jumpcount >= -10:
            neg = 1
            if jumpcount < 0:
                neg = -1
            y -= (jumpcount ** 2) /2 * neg
            jumpcount -= 1
        else:
            isjump = False
            jumpcount = 10
    win.fill((0, 0, 0))
    pygame.draw.rect(win, (255, 255, 255), (x, y, width, height))
    pygame.display.update()
pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 1):

The line `keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()` and the whole game logic and drawing code should not be in the event loop (`for event in pygame.event.get():`), otherwise the code gets executed once per event in the queue, and if no events are in the queue, it won't be executed at all.

You could just dedent `keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()` and all lines beneath.

Alternatively, you could check in the event loop if the space key was pressed (with `if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:`) and then set `isjump` to `True` (that means the player will only jump once per keypress).

```
import pygame


pygame.init()
win = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
x = 0
y = 490
width = 10
height = 10
vel = 5
isjump = False
jumpcount = 10

running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                isjump = True

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_a] and x > vel - 5:
        x -= vel
    elif keys[pygame.K_d] and x < 500 - width:
        x += vel

    if isjump:
        if jumpcount >= -10:
            neg = 1
            if jumpcount < 0:
                neg = -1
            y -= jumpcount**2 / 2 * neg
            jumpcount -= 1
        else:
            isjump = False
            jumpcount = 10

    win.fill((0, 0, 0))
    pygame.draw.rect(win, (255, 255, 255), (x, y, width, height))
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(30)

pygame.quit()
```

I also recommend adding a `pygame.time.Clock` instance and call `clock.tick(FPS)` to regulate the frame rate.

And I'd rather implement the jumping in [this way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46895412/6220679), with a gravity constant which gets added to the y-velocity each frame.